# What is the difference between a $\mathbb{K}$ vector space of finite dimension and $\mathbb{K}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

What is the difference between a $\mathbb{K}$ vector space of finite dimension $n \ge 1$, denoted $E$ and $\mathbb{K}^n$?

Comment: There is no difference in the sense that both vector spaces are isomorphic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a field $\Bbb K$, $\Bbb K^n$ refers the *particular vector space* $$(\Bbb K^n, +, \cdot)$$ with underlying space $$\Bbb K^n := \underbrace{\Bbb K \times \cdots \times \Bbb K}_n,$$
whose elements are $n$-tuples $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ of elements $x_a \in \Bbb K$ with pointwise addition and scalar multiplication operations, that is,
\begin{align}
(x_1, \ldots, x_n) + (y_1, \ldots, y_n) &:= (x_1 + y_1, \ldots, x_n + y_n) \\
s \cdot (x_1, \ldots, x_n) &:= (s x_1, \ldots, s x_n) .
\end{align}

On the other hand, the underlying space $E$ and operations $\oplus$ and $\odot$ of a vector space $(E, \oplus, \odot)$ over $\Bbb K$ of dimension $n$ have no particular form. Any basis ${\bf e}_a$ of $E$ (over $\Bbb K$) determines a vector space isomorphism $$\phi: \Bbb K^n \stackrel{\cong}{\to} E ,$$ given by
$$\phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = x_1 {\bf e}_1 + \cdots + x_n {\bf e}_n .$$ Every isomorphism $\Bbb K^n \to E$ is of this form, but in general a vector space $E$ has no preferred basis, and correspondingly there is no preferred isomorphism.